# Update three.js rev 62 to 63 - Error

Tags: javascript, three.js

I just updated the three.js lib from rev 62 to 63 and I now get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object -1.5707963267948966 has no method '_updateQuaternion' | three.min.js:150
```

According to the [migration page](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration) and [release notes](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases) there was no change which should affect my code. Has someone else experienced this lately and can point me to the right direction for fixing this?

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing any of your code.

Comment: You're right. I just wanted to isolate the problem so I could give more detail. It boiled down to a line which worked before but probably was not intented to work:

I did something like "mesh.rotation = ..." where I should use "mesh.rotation.x = ..."

Comment: That's what I was thinking might be the issue, since rotation seems to be the only things that gets calls `_updateQuaternion` in the source. Glad you figured it out!